# BadZipFile: File is not a zip file in docxtpl

Tags: python, djangorestframework, django-templates, error500, python-docx

Este es mi Código en view.py, no sé cómo hacer para exportar el archivo word.

estos son los paquetes que estoy utilizando

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from rest_framework.response import Response

from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

from io import BytesIO

from django.template import Template, Context

from .models import DocumentTemplate

class GenerateDocumentView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            template_id = request.data.get('template_id')
            data = request.data.get('data')
            format = request.data.get('format', 'text_plain')

            template = DocumentTemplate.objects.get(id=template_id)
            template_text = template.template_text

            t = Template(template_text)
            context = Context(data)
            document_content = t.render(context)

            if format == 'text_plain':
                return Response({'document': document_content})

            elif format == 'docx':
                print(1)
                doc = DocxTemplate(BytesIO())
                print(2)
                doc = DocxTemplate(BytesIO(document_content.encode('utf-8')))
                print(str(doc))
                doc_buffer = BytesIO()
                print(4)
                doc.save(doc_buffer)
                print(5)
                doc_buffer.seek(0)
                print(6)
                return Response(doc_buffer.getvalue(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')

            else:
                return Response({'error': 'Invalid format'}, status=400)

        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=500)
```

cuando el format es text_plain no tengo ningun problema, el problema resalta cuando es el format es docx, he intentado muchas cosas pero nose que pueda hacer, pero al parecer bien de la parte del codigo que dice "doc.save(doc_buffer)".

Lo que quiero hacer con el codigo es que el usuario pueda darme un json y que este tenga unos datos que voy a utilizar para remplazar en mi archivo template y dependiendo lo que usuario diga se lo devolveré en text_plain es decir la consola o en un archivo word. Tengo problemas con el archivo word.

en un archivo word. Tengo problemas con el archivo word

Comment: document_content debe ser una cadena de bytes que, volcada en un archivo, se pueda abrir perfectamente por cualquier programa que pueda abrir docx. Basicamente, un docx cargado en memoria. Es ese el caso? O es texto plano?